# Using result of SPARQL query in SQWRL

Tags: logic, sparql, ontology, semantic-web, sqwrl

I want to write a rule in SQWRL that uses some information about individuals in couple of time (say 90 days). for example consider following rule:

> If x be a Pie and y be a Pistachio and ""***the average number of y in all x from past 90 days be z***"" -> The cook is good.

I think I can calculate ***the average number of y in all x from past 90 days be z*** with SPARQL query but how can I use the output of query in SQWRL to make above query?
Please help if you know the answer and maybe you have another solution.

Comment: impossible in SQWRL and no, you can't embedd SPARQL result in SQWRL

Comment: @UninformedUser thank you. and what about another solution to do that?

Comment: why not trying plain SPARQL?